# Python function running truncate before user input

Tags: python

I'm learning python and trying to delete the contents of  a life after the user input. for some reason it deletes the contents of the .txt before it asks for user input. Can't seem to work it out.

```
from sys import argv
import sys

script, filename = argv   

 def erase_contents(f):
        user_input = input("> ")
        if user_input == "yes":
            current_file.truncate()
            print("successfully deleted")
        else:
            sys.exit()
current_file = open(filename, "w+")

print(f"Now we are going to erase the contents of {filename}. type yes to delete.")
erase_contents(current_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `truncate`, because you are opening the file using `w+` as the mode, which truncates the file *immediately*. You could use mode `a` instead, but really, there's no need to open the file *at all* until you determine that the user wants to truncate the file. You could just write

```
def erase_contents(fname):
    user_input = input("> ")
    if user_input == "yes":
        with open(fname, "w"):
            pass
    else:
        sys.exit()

print(f"Now we are going to erase the contents of {filename}. type yes to delete.")
erase_contents(filename)
```